# About question mark in regular expression

Tags: regex

I saw a regular expression says `(?i)`. So what does it mean when we put a question mark in front of a character？

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general it does not mean anything and might even result in an error (if the question mark does not follow a valid character). But there are certain characters where it does have an effect, namely if this character is also used as [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) says about this particular syntax:

> Modern regex flavors allow you to apply modifiers to only part of the regular expression. If you insert the modifier (`?ism`) in the middle of the regex, the modifier only applies to the part of the regex to the right of the modifier. You can turn off modes by preceding them with a minus sign. All modes after the minus sign will be turned off. E.g. (`?i-sm`) turns on case insensitivity, and turns off both single-line mode and multi-line mode.
>
> Not all regex flavors support this. JavaScript and Python apply all mode modifiers to the entire regular expression. They don't support the (`?-ismx`) syntax, since turning off an option is pointless when mode modifiers apply to the whole regular expressions. All options are off by default.
>
> You can quickly test how the regex flavor you're using handles mode modifiers. The regex `(?i)te(?-i)st` should match `test` and `TEst`, but not `teST` or `TEST`.

`?i` means that everything following these characters should be matched case-insensitive.

Also note that, as the text says, not all regex flavors support this syntax.

Comment: Great! Got it. BTW, it's a great website