# question mark in regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I saw this regular expression performed on an url:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/';
preg_match('/(http)(.*?)\n/', $url, $matches);
```

I am not sure what the use of the question mark "?" is in this regex expression. According to regex manuals, the "?" is a meta character that is equivalent to {0,1}. Then, what is the point of having "?" after an * since * already represents {0,}

Can someone please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: Check it out...may be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935319/about-question-mark-in-regular-expression

Comment: @Dikku that question is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has a different meaning when it follows another quantifier.

In this case it changes the matching behaviour of the preceding quantifier. The default behaviour is greedy and the the `?` changes it to "ungreedy".

- "Greedy" means match as much as possible
- "Ungreedy" means match as less as possible

See the [article on regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

**For example:**

`a.+b` will match "aabxb" in **aabxb**

`a.+?b` will match only "aab" in **aabxb**

See the example [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32mv5)

<sub>You may be interested in my blog post about this topic: [You do know Quantifiers. Really?](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=43)</sub>

**About your regex**

```
preg_match('/(http)(.*?)\n/', $url, $matches);
```

I don't think it makes a difference here. The `.` matches anything  but newline characters by default (you can change this by adding a `s` after the closing regex delimiter), so if the question mark is there or not, it will match only till the first `\n`.

If you change the behaviour by using `preg_match('/(http)(.*?)\n/s', $url, $matches);`, it will make a difference. `.*\n` would match till the last `\n` and `.*?\n` will stop at the first `\n`.

Comment: @tonytz, you are welcome, I added also an explanation for your special case.

Comment: Awww, I see. The added explanation is very helpful as well - in fact, it addressed the issue when the line is at the end of the file!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the question mark means a "stingy" match. It will stop matching as soon as the first `\n` is encountered, while otherwise, it would gobble up intervening `\n`s until the last.

More about greedy and stingy matching at http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/regexps.html