# What does the "(?i)" mean in Regex?

Tags: asp.net, regex

Regex pattern `(?i)(?<=<data name=")\w+(?=")` can capture **test** of

```
<data name="test" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>123</value>
</data>
```

But what does the "(?i)" mean in regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [About question mark in regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935319/about-question-mark-in-regular-expression)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a way of specifying that the matching should be case insensitive.

Here's the MSDN page on [Regex options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx):

> By applying inline options in a regular expression pattern with the syntax **(?imnsx-imnsx)**. The option applies to the pattern from the point that the option is defined to either the end of the pattern or to the point at which the option is undefined by another inline option.

But really, it looks like you're processing XML, in which case, you should really be using an XML parser, **not** regular expressions. There are classes built into the framework for working with XML which properly respect all of the rules of XML. Treating XML as "just a string" tends to lead to brittle solutions.

Comment: so i guess if you combine mine and your answer u get the actual answer :P